# Apache CXF web service response re-routing on web service client gone detection

Tags: web-services, cxf, apache-camel, soapui

Working with Apache Camel for EIP, I have an Apache CXF Web Service Endpoint which when called, will put requests into an MQ queue. Requests in that MQ queue are processed asynchronously where, responses are then generated and placed into a response MQ queue. The Apache CXF Web Service collects a request's response from the response MQ queue which it then writes to the Exchange's out channel for the calling client to receive.

Is it possible to configure my web service so that it can detect if a client is still connected when it is trying to send the asynchronous response back to it? And when this detect occurs, to route the response to another Camel route?

A use case scenario would be for example where the client makes a call to the web service but disconnects after 5 seconds of not receiving a response from the web service. And later, when the web service processes the request and fails to send the response to the no longer connected client, it re-routes the response to, for example, an smtp route.

*** UPDATE ***

Having read various online documentation and forum posts, I have my service configured as follows:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" handleFault="true">
    <routeBuilder ref="aServiceRoute" />
</camelContext>
```

and in my AServiceRoute route, I have configured my route as follows:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    onException(Exception.class).process(new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            log.debug("caught Exception A!!!");
        }});

    from(cxfUri)
        .onException(Exception.class).process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    log.debug("caught Exception B!!!");
                }}).end()
            .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    // do something..
                }
            })
    .to(ExchangePattern.InOut, mqUri);
```

For my first test, I force an Exception throw in the process where the `// do something..` comment is. When I run this test, I see the log `"caught Exception A!!!"` which is great.

For my second test, I basically run the test scenario I have described in this post. When I run this test, I see a cxf stacktrace logged:

```
=09-05-14 12:25:32 [WARN ] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor    for {http://camel.apache.org/cxf/jaxws/provider}DefaultPayloadProviderSEIService#{http://cxf.component.camel.apache.org/}invoke has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
```

but none of my route's onException() methods are called.

What am I missing? Do I need to place the onException() method somewhere else in service's route?

Thanks in advance, PM.

Answer (score 0):

The Dead Letter Channel will offer the behaviour you need: https://camel.apache.org/dead-letter-channel.html

Comment: Hi @Matthew, thanks for the response. I was thinking that the solution would be something along the lines of a dead letter error handler, etc. However, during testing, I am finding that if I disconnect the client in the middle of a call, the web service itself does not throw any exceptions or anything like that when it writes the response back to the Exchange's out channel. It is as though it doesn't care whether the client is still there or not. Shouldn't the service throw an exception at least if the client is no longer there during the response send stage of the routing process?

Comment: Does a soap fault get thrown? Camel won't treat a Soap fault as an exception as it is a valid response (albeit an error response). Set  handleFault to "true" on your camel context to convert soap faults to exceptions

Comment: handleFault doesn't seem to make any difference (unless I am setting it wrong?). My web service route is set roughly as follows: from("cxf:/AService?dataFormat=PAYLOAD").handleFault()...to(ExchangePattern.InOut, mqUri). I do also have a post-processor call where I modify the response message. Once modified, I write the response by calling exchange.getOut().setBody(response). I was expecting the exception or fault to occur during this final call?

Comment: You need to set it on your camel context: `camelContext.setHandleFault(true);`

Comment: My route is configured in a RouteBuilder class and in the configure() method I am now calling getContext().setHandleFault(true); but still no faults or exceptions seem to happen when I disconnect the client before the response is sent.

Comment: The lack of SOAPFaults, etc. is not due to server-side Camel web service configuration. It is actually, a client-side issue I think... When I call the web service using SoapUI client, I cancel the call mid-way and no SOAPFaults are generated when the service tries to write the response to the client. But if I call the web service via test code (e.g. using org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean) and cancel the call mid-way, then SOAPFaults are generated as would be expected. Can anyone explain how a SoapUI client connection would be treated differently by the Apache CXF web service?

Comment: Update: For some reason, in SoapUI 4.5.0, clicking the red button (Abort ongoing request) doesn't seem to actually close the client connection to the server. To make the test work, I am having to actually kill the SoapUI Windows process itself (possible SoapUI bug?). On the server-side however, I can now see a SoapFault stacktrace printed but, still no Camel error handling re-routing taking place. I have camelContext.handleFault set to true I believe but still cxf seems to be handling the SoapFault itself...